# TSQL PATINDEX Searching exact value in a comma seperated list

Tags: t-sql

Hi i need to control if my value is exists in a comma seperated list.

For example

```
DECLARE @list NVARCHAR = '6,3,67,34';

SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM Table1
WHERE PATINDEX ('%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Table1.ID) + '%', @list)
```

It should return rows which ID field is 6, 3, 67 or 34.

How can i do with or without PATINDEX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add leading and trailing commas to both `@list` and `Table1.ID` in the search:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
    FROM Table1
    WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Table1.ID) + ',', ',' + @list + ',') <> 0;
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @Gabe: No. I just copied that from the original question.

Comment: Thanks! Really helped me a lot (don't need to split anymore, doing JOINS, INs etc.)